# What are some emergency water purification methods?

Tags: safety, preparation, emergencies, water-purification

If you're lost in the wilderness (and you've foolishly left behind your handy dandy water purification tablets and water filter), what are some of the best and safest ways to purify water? What do you do if you don't have a metal pot to boil water in?

Comment: I would just drink water.

Comment: @gerrit http://mentalfloss.com/sites/default/files/styles/article_640x430/public/oregon-trail-dysentery_5.jpg

Comment: If you're truly in dire straits, you can collect rainwater or use some kind of solar still.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, you'll want some type of plastic bottle. You can cut the end off of your plastic bottle and layer in ground ( smashed ) charcoal from your camp fire along with cotton, sand, grass, most anything you can get your hands on to filter out the different sized particles. Charcoal being the most likely to weed out micro organisms.

http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Water-Filter

Or, with most water bottles you can string it above the fire and bring the water to a boil before the plastic melts if you're careful. This typically works best when the water bottle is completely full and capped.

If all that fails, remember that it's easier to treat diarrhea tomorrow than heat stroke today .

Comment: Would boiling a full and capped bottle make it blow up?

Comment: Like I said, it has to be done carefully. Even so, it wouldn't 'blow up,' but it could potentially rupture and leak.